# QGtkStyle could not resolve GTK

Tags: linux

I have installed Orange 3 in Ubuntu 18.04 using Anaconda. It runs just fine, but the menus appear as blank.

[image]

I obtain the following error when I execute it:

`QGtkStyle could not resolve GTK. Make sure you have installed the proper libraries.`

I have been trying to sort it for days without success.

Any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: why was this posted in two places?

Comment: I didn't know that Stackexchange and Stackoverflow were the same platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix has been published at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50583925/3866828

It works adding

`export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=gtk2`

at the end of the `~/.bashrc` file. Then it's a matter of executing
`source ~/.bashrc` to see the content of the menus the next time that Orange 3 is loaded.